# What are the consquences of poisoning the Bottle Street Gang's elixir for the Gentleman Callers quest?

Tags: dishonored

The first mission of the game, **High Overseer Campbell**, has an optional side quest called **Gentleman Callers.** The second part of the quest is to poison the elixir the Bottle Street Gang. I'd like to complete this quest since it will reward me with a rune, but I'm concerned that poisoning the elixir will have negative consequences, such as raising the chaos level. I've checked various online sources, but I can't seem to find a concrete answer.

What are the consequences of poisoning the elixir? Is there another way to complete the quest? If an alternative method for completing the quest does exist please put said method behind spoiler tags. I'd prefer to find the method myself, but don't want to waste time looking for a method which doesn't exist.

Comment: I have found a [couple forum posters stating that it's fine to poison the Elixir](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/636042-dishonored/64280885), but I'd prefer a more reliable source than a random person on a forum.

Comment: [My question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/89562/5398) intersects with yours, though it's not a duplicate. You may find some more information there.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What are the consequences of poisoning the elixir?

You'd earn another rune from Granny Rags, and there's a bone charm in the distillery where you'll be poisoning the elixir supply . Also, there are some dialogue changes with NPCs, most notably Slackjaw (when you deal with him in a later mission).

> Slackjaw and his gang sell a cheaper bootleg version of [Sokolov's
>  elixir](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Sokolov%27s_Elixir). Slackjaw would mention that someone poisoned the elixir supply in the distillery,
>  when you deal with him in a [later mission](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/House_of_Pleasure). I also remember guards or
>  an in-game note mentioning that the guards also use Slackjaw's elixir
>  as it is cheaper (when you have not poisoned the elixir supply).

I believe its effects on chaos will depend on [*how* you did](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90107/4797) that part of the quest (not whether you did that quest or not). Also, you *risk* higher chaos if you choose to do it.

You may also be curious on how this will affect the part of '[The Flooded District](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/The_Flooded_District)' mission...

> ..where you'll be meeting Slackjaw and Granny Rags again.

I have done two separate playthroughs: one where I have not poisoned the elixir supply, and another one where I poisoned it. I can say that it will *not* affect that part of 'The Flooded District' mission.

---

> Is there another way to complete the quest?

There is no alternative method to complete that quest, AFAIK. The alternative is not to do the second part of the quest at all. Avoiding it will make getting the 'Ghost' and 'Shadow' achievements much easier, and has less high chaos risk (but will prevent you from getting the Gentlemen Caller and Street Conspiracy achievements, aside from the rune and bone charm previously mentioned). [(Source)](http://www.ign.com/wikis/dishonored/High_Overseer_Campbell)

Comment: +1, very thorough answer. It was my understanding that poisoning the elixir also increased the percentage of the population infected with the plague -  that is to say the number of weepers -  in later levels, but I haven't been able to do the research to confirm this. It would make logical sense however. Either way, it's not a particularly major impact on gameplay or the narrative overall.

Comment: When I returned to the distillery for the Golden Cat mission, there were three weepers locked up outside the distillery. In addition a wave of weepers attacked the distillery as I was leaving. (This was after poisoning the still.)

Comment: @Nick I noticed that too. I'm not sure, however, if that is due to poisoning the elixir supply, or due to high chaos. Comment back if you find out anything more about this.

Answer (score 3):

This answer doesn't directly address the game mechanic but as far as the story goes, anyone worried about the moral implications may be interested in reading a note that can be found on a table in the second half the warehouse:

> Recipe For Craxton
>  =================
>
>  Craxton,
>
>  I'm coming tomorrow to check on the batch.  Make sure you're wearing pants this time, and stick to the recipe:
>
>  1 part Sokolov's elixir
>  1 part beechgum paste
>  2 parts sugar water
>
>  That's it.  The more of the real shit you cut in, the less there is to spread around and the less coin I make.  This ain't a charity.
>
>  Slackjaw

The inference being that the bootleg elixir wouldn't be effective against the plague anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I saw there is no consequence to poisoning the still, other than a shiny new rune, it does not affect the mission and therefore has no real affect on the play through aside from a slight increase in the number of weepers and unlocking a non-lethal option in a later mission.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the poisoning does affect the mission with the golden cat. If you listen to the dialogue, you will hear them say the "free loaders" drank the tainted elixir.
Also not doing this mission "trying to kill granny" will result in a rat swarm.
But however without doing so, you won't get the last rune

Answer (score -1):

You can get the rewards without poisoning: I followed granny after she asked me and just took the rune.  She attacked and after shooting her with a sleep dart, she disappeared.  I still went to the distillery and grabbed the bone charm but have not used the poison.

I don't know if it means I am low chaos or am missing out on a story progression.

Comment: Hi Marcel - this isn't an answer to the original question so shouldn't be posted here. There's a big, friendly 'Ask A Question' button in the top right of the page :)

Comment: Well Alex it is somewhat of an answer followed by a "what if?".  If you accidentally eliminate the granny quest, is there repercussions?

Comment: Nevertheless, please limit your responses to answers only. I edited your response here accordingly.

Comment: This is also incorrect - the rune you can pickup in her basement is in addition to the one you get for completing the quest (which only appears once you have).