# What happens if I refuse to do Granny Rags' quest where she asks to poison the elixir supply? (spoilers)

Tags: dishonored

Say, we refuse to accept Granny Rags' quest where she asks to poison the elixir supply located in the bandit area - Does this imply that Slackjaw will not give out the non-lethal version of the quest for killing the twin brothers?

Since he explicitly says that he only asks for our help because many of his men were poisoned by the elixir, so half of his gang group are now Weepers. So, if we don't touch the elixir by not doing Granny Rags' quest, will we not get non-lethal version of the main quest? i.e. Will he not ask us to get the safe code?

Comment: Could you please explain your downvote as I don't even know what is wrong with the question...Pressing down arrow and walking away does not feel so good. :-)

Comment: Ok, I've added spoiler tags hopefully this is the reason.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, but you're worrying a little too much about it.  They're not personal; they're based on the question itself.

Comment: i am not worrying, I just wanted to hear alternative storyline. Nvm, thanks for sanity. :-)

Comment: I didn't downvote your quesiton, but I do find your question a little unclear. I'm really not sure what you're asking. Your question title is also really poor. That may be why you were downvoted. You should edit your title to actually be a question (don't worry about spoilers), and try to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Updated. Better?

Comment: Related: [What are the consequences of poisoning the Bottle Street Gang's elixir for the Gentleman Callers quest?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/94095/4797)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of your interactions with Granny Rags, Slackjaw will offer you the non-lethal way of dealing with the Twins.  His dialog changes somewhat, but otherwise the quest is exactly the same.  I ran this both ways - one run through the game I helped Granny Rags, and in the other I avoided her altogether.  Both times I non-lethally dealt with the Twins with Slackjaw's help.

If you haven't poisoned Slackjaw's elixir machine, though, you can use it when you return to his hideout later.

If you bypass Granny Rags altogether:

> You'll also skip the quest towards the end of the game where you have to either assist Slackjaw from escaping Granny Rags or assist Granny Rags with Slackjaw.  The gate you'd normally need to find the key to is simply unlocked - there's no reason to go to Granny Rags' hideout.

Comment: What about investigation of the fallen fellow bandit in the manor? Btw I finished the game but still do not really know who killed him? Granny?

Comment: And also seems killing Granny later is counted towards murder case therefore you can't get "didn't kill anyone" chapter achievement? I've killed somehow two people(though I only used choke) so can't really figure out whether granny counted towards these kills.

Comment: @Aubergine, (WARNING: SPOILERS) you'll still investigate the dead bandit in the same house - the quest for Slackjaw is identical.  It's possible to clear the last quest in this line without killing either of them - you just have to sleep dart Granny after burning the Cameo

Comment: Will you get the final quest if you just refuse to do the poisoning?

Comment: @svick, If I remember correctly, yes.  I did the final quest in this line non-lethally, which meant I also did not poison anyone earlier (just in case that counted as a kill).